# Is it possible to use Spring @Cache* on Feign client?

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava, feign

I have a Feign client that requests a token from a microservice. 
Since I am making multiple calls, I would like to cache the responses received from the Feign client and use Spring Guava caching, but it doesn't seem to work. All I have is the configuration class and the annotation on the Feign client.

I read somewhere on stack overflow that Feign might not support @Cacheable annotation. Is this true?

Answer (score 10):

Finally, I managed to solve my issue. 
What I did in the end is :

-> Create new @Service annotated class

-> Inject interface with @FeignClient annotation

-> Put all @Cache related annotations ( using @Caching annotation) on the method that calls methods from the interface.

It works! :)

Comment: can you explain this?

Answer (score 7):

Annotating Feign clients with `@Cacheable` now works out of the box with Spring Cloud OpenFeign, as per [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#feign-caching), since [version 3.1.0](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/02/spring-cloud-2021-0-0-codename-jubilee-has-been-released) (as part of Spring Cloud 2021.0.0).

You only need to make sure that:

- you have configured `@EnableCaching`
- you are using `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign` 3.1.0+ in your dependencies, so this normally means importing [`spring-cloud-dependencies` version 2021.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2021.0.0)+ ([they switched to calver in 2020](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/17/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-m1-released#notable-changes-in-the-2020-release-train))
- you are using Spring Boot 2.4.1+ (required for this version of Spring Cloud)

Comment: Now I still have to understand why it seems to work for me without upgrading Spring Cloud…

Answer (score 4):

What Bianca supposed to do is to add a @Service annotated class to her project where she can use @cacheable annotation.

The traditional way to use FeignClient is to have only an interface annotated with @FeignClient, and then call these methods form other projects/classes. She has added a @Service annotated class, where she call her feignclients methods caching whatever she want.

### Traditional:

FeignClient class:

```
@FeignClient(name="my_feign-client", url = "http://myurl.com/")
public interface MyFeignClient {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() throws FeignException;
```

Class where to call feign client method:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyFeignClient myFeignClient ;
    
    public String callTest() {
    ...
        return myFeignClient.test();
    }
```

### Bianca's method:

Feign client class remains the same.

Service class with cache:

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames={"test"})
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    private MyFeignClient myFeignClient ;
    
    @Cacheable
    public String callCachedTest() {
    ...
    return myFeignClient.test();
}
```

And last, the class to call the cached method, that call feignClient:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService ;
    
    public String callTest() {
    ...
        return testService.callCachedTest();
    }
```